# How to do a JOIN in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have two tables `Users` and `User_Org`.

- Users ( user_id,first name,last name, active_ind, email)
- User_Org (user_id, org_id)

I have to write a Oracle SQL query, where it should return all users whose active_ind is 1 and org_id of associated user in User_org match the given org_id.

I have tried below, it is not working

```
select *
from Users u
  join User_ORG  org        
where org.ORGANIZATION_ID = 12345 
  and Active_ind != 0;
```

Comment: <> is SQL for != .  Aside from that you've got no join conditions

Comment: Please read the manual for the correct syntax of the `JOIN` operator: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDIJFDJ

Comment: @LoztInSpace: even though `!=` is non-standard it does work in Oracle (and pretty much every DBMS)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `on` clause of the `join`. Other than that, if you want users with an `active_ind` of `1`, I'd state that directly with an equality check (`=`) instead of dancing around it with an inequality check.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM  users u
JOIN  user_org org ON u.user_id = org.user_id
WHERE org.org_id = 12345 AND active_ind = 1
```

Comment: @prashanth: don't forget to accept this answer. To do so, click the tick to the left of the answer, so that it turns green. This is how we mark questions as completed here.